# cannot execute filename.o file in cygwin with gcc

Tags: gcc

I have a build shell script that reads as follows,

```
#!/bin/sh

gcc -o posture.exe main.c posture_algorithm.c
```

Then I run the following command to set permission,

```
chmod 755 posture_algo.o
```

followed by,

```
./posture_algorithm.o
```

I get the following error,

```
-bash: ./posture_algo.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posture_algo.o` is a file containing object code. The executable your script creates is `posture.exe`, so you should be running:

```
chmod +x  posture.exe
./posture.exe
```